# trigger an event in another activity

Tags: android, android-event

is there a way trigger an event in another activity which might be below the current activity in the stack (the activity below the current activity is not a part of my application)

for eg: if activity 'Act1' of application 'A' launches Activity 'Act12' of appliication 'AB', then is there a way for 'Act12' to trigger an event (like a `backButtonPressed()` or `onPause()` etc) for 'Act1' ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think using intents we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only be able to do this if you have access to the source code of both applications, via an `intent-filter` in the hidden application, or if the second application already has an intent filter specified that does what you want it to do. `onPause()` will be called anyway as soon as an `Activity` is hidden